# creating function to subset the data frame and then take mean of particular column in r

Tags: r, functional-programming, subset, pipeline

Hoping to get some help on this
I have a data frame :

```
df<- data.frame(gem = c(Ruby, Opal, Topaz, Ruby, Ruby,Opal),
                cut = c(2,3,4,5,6,2))
```

Now the function I am aiming to make is to take subset first i.e. where gem is Ruby and then take mean of cut from that subset.

I have tried using following:

```
abc <- function(x,column1,val,coulmn2){
x%>%
subset(column1 %in% val)%>%
mean(na.omit(column2))}
abc(df,gem,"Ruby",cut)
```

This is not working but in above example ideally the answer should be 4.3

Comment: Isn't this just `mean(df[df$gem =="Ruby","cut"],na.rm=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you don't even have to write a function, there's a bunch of ways to do that, for example:

```
> aggregate(cut~gem, data=df, mean, na.rm=T)
    gem      cut
1  Opal 2.500000
2  Ruby 4.333333
3 Topaz 4.000000
```

Or

```
> tapply(df$cut, df$gem, mean, na.rm=T)
    Opal     Ruby    Topaz 
2.500000 4.333333 4.000000
```

If you really want to write a function that only gives out one value, then a `base` package one is:

```
> abc<- function(df, column1, val, column2){
+   mean(df[which(df[,column1] == val), column2], na.rm=T)
+   }
> abc(df, "gem", "Ruby", "cut")
[1] 4.333333
```

Comment: Thanks :) that is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to do with the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

df<- data.frame(gem = c("Ruby", "Opal", "Topaz", "Ruby", "Ruby","Opal"),
                cut = c(2,3,4,5,6,2))
df %>% group_by(gem) %>% summarize(mean(cut))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     gem `mean(cut)`
  <fctr>       <dbl>
1   Opal    2.500000
2   Ruby    4.333333
3  Topaz    4.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abc <- function(x,column1,val,column2){
           x[x[,column1] %in% val, column2] %>%
           na.exclude %>%  
           mean
        }
abc(df,"gem","Ruby","cut")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(cut = mean(cut)), by = gem]
#    gem      cut
#1:  Ruby 4.333333
#2:  Opal 2.500000
#3: Topaz 4.000000
```

#### data

```
df<- data.frame(gem = c("Ruby", "Opal", "Topaz", "Ruby", "Ruby","Opal"),
            cut = c(2,3,4,5,6,2))
```